# originalPayload not the same as message.originalPayload in groovy scripts

Tags: mule

I found that `originalPayload` does not do the same as `message.originalPayload` in groovy expressions. That is, the following transformers do not do the same thing:

with `originalPayload`:

```
<expression-transformer evaluator="groovy" expression="originalPayload" />
```

with `message.originalPayload`:

```
<expression-transformer evaluator="groovy" expression="message.originalPayload" />
```

The following mule configuration and test case can be used to reproduce the issue:

```
<mule ...>
    <flow name="test">
        <vm:inbound-endpoint name="test.Name" path="test.Path"
            exchange-pattern="request-response" />

        <expression-transformer evaluator="string" expression="bar" />

        <expression-transformer evaluator="groovy" expression="originalPayload" />
        <!-- or alternatively -->
        <!-- <expression-transformer evaluator="groovy" expression="message.originalPayload" /> -->
    </flow>
</mule>
```

The test case can be:

```
@Test
public void transformers() throws MuleException {
    final MuleClient client = muleContext.getClient();
    final MuleMessage reply = client.send("vm://test.Path", 1, null, RECEIVE_TIMEOUT);
    assertEquals(1, reply.getPayload());
}
```

The alternative with `message.originalPayload` works as expected. The one with `originalPayload` does not and the following exception is shown in the logs:

```
Exception stack is:
1. Expression Evaluator "groovy" with expression "originalPayload" returned null 
but a value was required. (org.mule.api.expression.RequiredValue Exception)
```

What could I be doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `expression-transformer` and `scripting:transformer` use a different set of bindings than the one used by a `scripting:component`, and this because they call a different method in `org.mule.module.scripting.component.Scriptable`.

Moreover, when `originalPayload` gets bound, it is with the wrong value:

```
bindings.put("originalPayload", event.getMessage().getPayload());
```

Hence: [MULE-6215](http://www.mulesoft.org/jira/browse/MULE-6215)

Answer (score 0):

Following the [Scripting Module Reference](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/Scripting+Module+Reference), they should be the same.

Also, if you take a look to org.mule.module.scripting.component.Scriptable in the scripting module, you will find that "originalPayload" is message.getPayload.

Can you post a small project reproducing the error?

```
public void populateBindings(Bindings bindings, MuleMessage message)
{
    populateDefaultBindings(bindings);
    if (message == null)
    {
        message = new DefaultMuleMessage(NullPayload.getInstance(), muleContext);
    }
    bindings.put("message", message);
    //This will get overwritten if populateBindings(Bindings bindings, MuleEvent event) is called
    //and not this method directly.
    bindings.put("payload", message.getPayload());
    //For backward compatability
    bindings.put("src", message.getPayload());
}

public void populateBindings(Bindings bindings, MuleEvent event)
{
    populateBindings(bindings, event.getMessage());
    bindings.put("originalPayload", event.getMessage().getPayload());
    bindings.put("payload", event.getMessage().getPayload());
    bindings.put("eventContext", new DefaultMuleEventContext(event));
    bindings.put("id", event.getId());
    bindings.put("flowConstruct", event.getFlowConstruct());
    if (event.getFlowConstruct() instanceof Service)
    {
        bindings.put("service", event.getFlowConstruct());
    }
}
```

Comment: Hard for me to post files. I work in an environment where that is restricted. The project could be easily created, however, with the information I posted on the original question.